# Read file contents directly to a stream avoiding use of array

Tags: c++, iostream

The below code's purpose is to read data from a file in chunks and then call a function passing in this chunked data.

```
std::ifstream fileData("file.jpg", std::ios::binary);
const int chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;

char* buffer = new char[chunkSize];
fileData.read(buffer, chunkSize);
std::istringstream chunkedFileData(std::string(buffer, chunkSize));

fcn(chunkedFileData); // void fcn(std::istream& s);
```

Currently, I use `istream::read` to extract a specific number of characters and store in the buffer array. Then I construct a `istringstream` from the buffer, because the following function expects a reference to an `istream`.

Is it possible to avoid the use of the intermediate array and read a specific number of characters to a stream?

Comment: Why can't you simply use `fcn(fileData)` in the example above?

Comment: Does `fcn()` have an overload where you can specify the maximum number of characters to read? If so, you can pass `fileData` directly to `fcn()`.

Comment: @G.M. There is a file size limitation.

Comment: @cdhowie Are you suggesting that I pass in the length and then move the read into the fcn? If that is the case I can't change the fcn.

Comment: @user870130 `fcn()` should already be reading whatever it needs to since it accepts an `std::istream`. If you can't change the function, you could wrap `fileData` in an istream wrapper that limits the amount of readable data.

Comment: Do you need to extract the content of your file into `istringstream` directly?

Comment: @k-five Yes, this is what I would like to be able to do.

Comment: okay but the whole content or not? a chuck only?

Comment: @k-five A chunk at a time. The full implementation would have a loop.

Comment: So you do not want to pass `fileData` object to the `fcn` because you need a chuck of the content. Am I right?

Comment: @k-five Yes, you're correct.

Comment: In theory you could do it by using `setbuf` member function of the `basic_streambuf` but I tested that and it did not work. [You can read this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf)